# word count in python with Flask

Tags: python-2.7, flask-wtforms

I am creating page using HTML with flask server,write function in python to search word in plain text file (demo.txt) ,my code is work fine return the correct word. i want to count the number of time the words appear in the text

```
def getText(self,word):
     try:

       myfile=open("E:\Python_work\demo.txt","r");
        mylist=[];
        text=word;
        for line in myfile:
            if text in line:
                   mylist.append(line);
        return mylist;
        myfile.close();
     except:
        return err;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
def getText(self, word):
    try:
        counter = 0
        myfile=open("D:\\demo.txt","r");
        for line in myfile:
            counter += line.count(word)
        myfile.close()
        return counter
    except:
        return err
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to count the number of occurrences of a word, why does the function return a list? Surely you'd want to return the number of occurrences?

You could try something like this:

```
myfile = open('/path', 'r')
text = word
word_count = 0
for line in myfile:
    if text in line:
        word_count += 1

myfile.close()
return word_count
```

EDIT: above code within a try block of course.

Sidenote: semicolons are bad style in Python. When you use them, the interpreter considers each line to be two statements, with the second statement being blank. Python's interpreter uses whitespace to know when statements end.

Comment: the above approach is wrong. let suppose if you have 2 words per line then it will count as 1.

Comment: I try to return the concordance result in the return of the function but it is not work for me so i try with list it is work fine.if you now how to return the concordance result in html file will be better for me.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say ?

Comment: i am saying i write this part of code first using concordance but the result is always come empty

Comment: 'def find(self.word)

f=open("e:\python_work\demo.txt","r")
text=f.read()
text1=text.split()
abstracts=nltk.Text(text1)
result=abstracts.concordance(word)
return result'

Comment: @HassanMehmood damn, you're right. What you could do is take each line and split it by ' ', and then iterate through that list and increment the word count each time the word is found.

Comment: @WimKeir OR you could just read the whole file 'c = f.read()' and count the occurrence of given word like this 'count = c.count('myword')' :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the count method for string to get total count. Below is the function to count the number of words in a text file.

```
def count_words(word_to_be_count):
    with open("E:\Python_work\demo.txt","r") as f:
        content = f.read()
        total_count = content.count(word_to_be_count)
    return total_count
```

Comment: @SMO this function will count only the word which you pass into this function

Answer (score 0):

The following would be a good way to do it in Python - assuming that the function is part of a class definition:

```
def getText(self, word):
    with open("D:\\demo.txt") as f:
        return f.read().count(word)
```

This assumes you'll handle the exception (if the file does not exist) in the caller. Otherwise use a try/except and return a suitable failure value:

```
def getText(self, word):
    try:
        with open("D:\\demo.txt") as f:
            return f.read().count(word)
    except IOError:
        return -1
```

Comment: ,thanks but i did not want to count all the word in the text file ,i want just to count the number of the appearance of the search word in the return text